# Clearing EditText in filtering recyclerview list doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, filtering

This is my code for filtering in MainActivity

```
search!!.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
                adapter!!.filter.filter(charSequence.toString())           
            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {}
        })
```

and this is my code in Adapter class

```
override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
        //new list for filtering
                newList.clear()
                val results = FilterResults()
                if (constraint.isNullOrBlank()) {
        //dataList is a list with data from mainActivity
                    newList!!.addAll(dataList!!)
                } else {
                    val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim { it <= ' ' }
                    for (item in dataList) {
                        if (item.sv_number.toString().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                            newList!!.add(item)
                        }
                    }
                }
                results.values = newList
                results.count = newList!!.size       
                return results
            }

            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                if (newList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    Log.d("there is nothing", "nothing")
                } else dataList.clear()
                dataList.addAll(newList)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
```

Filtering works fine, if I type for example 123, it will filter that. But when I delete what I have entered(123), it doesnt go back to old view, with all of the data, so I can search it again. The new filtered view with filtered data is only shown. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using dataList to display list in recycler view.
The problem is here after filtering dataList is modified. So when you delete search text there is no list with original data to load it back filtered elements.
What i am suggesting create a list which holds original data say originalList. First load copy this(originalList) to dataList.

modify your code

```
 if (constraint.isNullOrBlank()) {
    //originalList is a list with data from mainActivity
                newList!!.addAll(originalList!!)
            } else {
                val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim { it <= ' ' }
                for (item in originalList) {
                    if (item.sv_number.toString().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        newList!!.add(item)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, i created a copy of dataList, and it works now!